# how to adjust height of image css

Tags: html, css

I have an image, in which I am trying to resize based on the size of the screen. So if it is on desktop, then set width to `376px`, but if it isn't desktop, just leave it, my other css will do the work. So I have this:

```css
.gaimage {
    height: 376px;
}

.gaimage img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 376px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gaimage">
 <a href="gianluca.html">
 <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/908/200/300.jpg?hmac=guEHon4cM5wVkD_yaCyg37gD09iEjrpqzKfo-YU-Iwc">
</a></div>
```

however, it is not adjusting the height of the image. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Do you have a specific viewport width that you determine it will be 'not a desktop' ? If example, if the viewport reaches 800px, you want the image height to change? Use media queries for that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a media query ? Something like

```css
.gaimage img {
  width: 100%;
}  
@media all and (min-width:1300px){
  .gaimage img {
    height: 376px;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks 4 the answer. I have not tried that yet, however, i think there is something wrong with the way i am doing the .gaimage img , because when i define a css class (gaimage) and use it in the class tag in the img, it doesn't effect it at all, which is extremley strange, so I tried this, and it didn't effect anything

Comment: please see this codepen https://codepen.io/gianlucaas/pen/dyWwjwq . you can see that chnaging the height of the image doesn't change anything, because the div class is not effecting the image. not sure why

Comment: @gianluca image is not visible in codepen

Comment: On other screens what size u need for image?